# Загрузка и отображение шаблона

Tags: php, magento

Нужно загрузить и отобразить страницу за шаблоном! Страница загружается, но не отображается содержимое шаблона. `(Magento Full Release - ver 1.9.2.4)`

Сначала создаю в `/app/design/frontend/` свою директорию `news` в ней `newstheme` а в ней `/layout/vitaliydev_news.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <vitaliydevnews_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" template="vitaliydev_news/index.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </vitaliydevnews_index_index>
</layout>
```

Потом в (путь к моему шаблону):

```
/app/design/frontend/newstheme/template/vitaliydev_news/index.phtml
```

делаю такой контент в файле шаблона:

```
<h1>Template ews/index.phtml</h1>
```

*Часть конфига где подключаю layout:*

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <vitaliydevnews>
            <file>vitaliydev_news.xml</file>
        </vitaliydevnews>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

*И action в Контролере:*

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Страница загружается но не отображается контент шаблона.

Что я делаю не так? Если можно - прошу подсказки.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам нужно убедиться что у вас включена ваша тема **newstheme** из пакета **news** в настройках в админке для текущего стор вью.

Затем исправьте путь к шаблону, т.к. у вас пропущен пакет (**news**):

```
/app/design/frontend/newstheme/template/vitaliydev_news/index.phtml
```

Должно быть:

```
/app/design/frontend/news/newstheme/template/vitaliydev_news/index.phtml
```

После этого все должно нормально отображаться.